# Time spent on each state of workflow (JIRA)

Tags: time, jira, tracking, tempo

We are setting JIRA and we created a custom workflow for tickets (lets say it is analysing -> developing -> testing -> closed). We would like to see time spent (logged work) for every state of workflow in every ticket. For example I would see, that analysis took 2 days, development 3 hours etc. Is there any way, how to do this? We have Tempo plugin installed.

Is it also possible to aggregate coments by the state of the ticket? I mean I would see all coments for state Analysis on one place, then for Development below it and so on.

Thanks for any reply

Comment: I can tell by experience that trying to get a report based on logs per workflow status is not a good idea. (I am an Atlassian partner by the way) If you need to see logs separately, you should use subtasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About tracking time for each workflow state seperately:

As pointed out at [Atlassian Answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/178666/track-time-or-work-logged-during-each-workflow-step-status) you could achieve something like that.

For something convenient you would need something like suggested at [Tracking the Time Taken for Each Workflow Transition](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Tracking+the+Time+Taken+for+Each+Workflow+Transition)

---

Filtering comments by specific workflow states is another thing. I couldn't find any available plugins for that. And I doubt disabling the current comment issue tab panel and creating your own is an option for you.